# Keras CosineSimilarity - Positive or Negative

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, cosine-similarity

I'm training a model, my loss function is cosine similarity:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity, 
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)])
```

In Keras, "cosine_similarity" [loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/cosine_similarity) should converge to **-1**?

On the other hand, "CosineSimilarity" [metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/CosineSimilarity) should go towards **1** for better accuracy, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

As this is implemented as a **loss** and we minimize the **loss** during training the sign is inverted, so that when you minimize the **loss** (towards -1), the actual **similarity** is maximized towards 1. I also think that the documentation in the Stable release is a bit confusing, see the [Nightly documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/cosine_similarity?version=nightly) with this example:

```
y_true = [[0., 1.], [1., 1.], [1., 1.]]
y_pred = [[1., 0.], [1., 1.], [-1., -1.]]
loss = tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(y_true, y_pred, axis=1)
loss.numpy()
array([-0., -0.999, 0.999], dtype=float32)
```

For some reason the **metric** is also implemented with a - (minus).

Comment: `loss: -0.9608 - cosine_similarity: -0.9117 - val_loss: -0.8188 - val_cosine_similarity: -0.9117` My _loss_ goes towards -1, which is as expected as you explained. What about _cosine_similarity_ metric, it should also converge to -1, right?

Comment: Hi @isydmr - I am sorry ... seems like `CosineSimilarity` can be **both** a [loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CosineSimilarity?version=nightly) and a [metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/CosineSimilarity?version=nightly). If you implement it as a metric, then according to the documentation it should in fact converge to 1 as your fit improves.